# Is the product of $T_i$ spaces always a $T_i$ space?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am doing some topology and wondering about the following. If $X_j$ is a $T_i$ space for some $i \in \{1,2,3,3.5,4\}$. Does it then follow that $\Pi_j X_j$ is again a $T_i$ space?
I think for $i=2$ it is true and for $4$ it is false, but I am not sure about the other ones. Maybe, it also depends on the index set(whether it is finite, infinite (countable), etc.).

I am not asking for a proof, cause I would rather prefer to prove this by my own then.

Comment: Of those listed, $4$ is the only one that isn't (necessarily) inherited by products or subspaces. I don't remember how $T_5$ and $T_6$ behave, but an inkling says they are inherited. $T_0$ and $T_{2.5}$ are also inherited by products and subspaces.

Comment: @DanielFischer tank you this helped a lot.

Comment: @DanielFischer: The Sorgenfrey line is perfectly normal.

Comment: @ArthurFischer So not products, only subspaces, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daniel Fischer stated above the product of two $T_4$ spaces is not necesarrily not $T_4$.

Here is an example: Consider the set $X=\mathbb R$ and the topology on X with is generated by  the following basis:

$$[a,b),a<b$$

Then the product $X\times X$ is not $T_4$

The topological space $X$ is called [Sorgenfrey line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorgenfrey_line) and $X \times X$ is called [Sorgenfrey plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorgenfrey_plane).

Comment: Note that the Sorgenfrey line is [completely (or hereditarily) normal](http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Hereditarily_normal_space) (or T$_5$) and even [perfectly normal](http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Perfectly_normal_space) (or T$_6$). This example therefore shows that the product of T$_5$ (and T$_6$) spaces may fail to be T$_4$.

Answer (score 0):

The product of $T_i$-spaces is again $T_i$ for $i=0,1,2$. Also, the product of regular or completely regular spaces has again that property. It follows that the product of $T_i$ spaces is again $T_i$ for all $i\le 3.5$.

For (completely) regular spaces, try to show the property holds for a point $x=(x_i)_i$ and a basic open neighborhood of the form $U_{i_1}\times...\times U_{i_k}$.